# Two-column HTML/CSS right column scrolling - left column stay put - easiest way to accomplish this?

Tags: html, css

I have a two-column layout and I want the left column to stay put and the right column to be scrollable.  What's the easiest way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Do you mean something like this? See http://jsfiddle.net/NGLN/bePrn/.

Tested on Win7 in IE7, IE8, IE9, Opera 11, FF 4, Chrome 12, SafariWin 5.

Comment: The problem with this is that if you hold the mouse over your left container, you won't be able to scroll.

Comment: Exactly.  I don't want the left column to scroll at all.

Comment: @user661152 Maybe you misunderstood. The right column won't scroll if you wheel the mouse when the mouse is over the left column.

Answer (score 5):

You could make two `div` elements with CSS-property `overflow: auto`. This will give you kind of an `iframe` style box - this also means that this won't be the default scrolling area.

Another possibility is to use [fixed positioning](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/position.html) on your static (unscrollable) column.

The could be accomplished with something like this:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <style>
    #left {
        width: 200px;
        position: fixed;
        top: 0;
        bottom: 0;
        left: 0;
        background: #ffa;
    }
    #right {
        margin-left: 200px;
    }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="left">
        Static container
    </div>
    <div id="right">
        Lots of scrollable content goes here
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I think is the correct answer. `position: fixed` is not used often but it's perfect for something like this because `fixed` positions itself relative to the `viewport`. No need to set the height in the html or body. From what I have gathered, if possible, it is best practice to avoid setting the height with html and body.